# Please help me for android recovery

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I am using Symphony xplorer w35.

I wanted to install a custom ROM on it, so I backed up the the original ROM (normally, without using CWM recovery). After that, I installed CWM recovery mode on it. Then, I wiped my data & cache and installed a custom ROM, but I forgot to backup the previous ROM using CWM! Now, when I wanted to restore the previous ROM, it is impossible!

The previous backup is a .backup file & CWM can't restore it. I have to restore it via normal recovery mode, but whenever I turn on recovery mode, CWM mode automatically comes there! How to restore my previous ROM?

Comment: Usually you can download the stock ROM from your manufacturer's website.

Comment: Use **Sp Flash tool** to flash Stock ROM on your device. Then restore the backup using the normal Recovery. It will work. [Here](http://xdafirmware.com/symphony-w35) are the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can download the stock ROM for your device: [Stock ROM for Symphony Xplorer W35](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B-9tyB-auwzhZGpQMGRVNUQ2Nzg)

Instructions:

### How to Flash

**Step 1**: Download and extract the stock firmware on your computer.

**Step 2**: After extracting you will find the SP Flash Tool, Driver and instruction manual.

**Step 3**: Install the USB Drivers (skip if drivers are already installed).

**Step 4**: Open the SP Flash Tool and load the Scatter File from the firmware folder.

**Step 5**: Connect your Smartphone to the computer using the USB Driver.

**Step 6**: Click on Upgrade / Download Button in the SP Flash Tool to Begin the Flashing.

**Step 7**: Green Ring will appear at the end of successful Flash.

For more detailed instruction with images: [Detailed Instructions with Images](http://androidxda.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool)

Source: http://xdafirmware.com/symphony-w35

Hope my answer helps!